# What is character encoding and why should I bother with it

Tags: encoding, character-encoding

I am quite confused about the concept of *character encoding*.

What is Unicode, GBK, etc? How does a programming language use them?

Do I need to bother knowing about them? Is there a simpler or faster way of programming without having to trouble myself with them?

Comment: The classic off-site resource for this is Joel Spolsky's essay [_The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)_](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html).

Comment: If you were directed here through a duplicate, perhaps see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 43, accepted):

(Note that I'm using some of these terms loosely/colloquially for a simpler explanation that still hits the key points.)

A byte can only have 256 distinct values, being 8 bits.

Since there are character sets with more than 256 characters in the character set one cannot in general simply say that each character is a byte.

Therefore, there must be mappings that describe how to turn each character in a character set into a sequence of bytes.  Some characters might be mapped to a single byte but others will have to be mapped to multiple bytes.

Those mappings are encodings, because they are telling you how to encode characters into sequences of bytes.

As for Unicode, at a very high level, Unicode is an attempt to assign a single, unique number to every character.  Obviously that number has to be something wider than a byte since there are more than 256 characters :)  Java uses a version of Unicode where every character is assigned a 16-bit value (and this is why Java characters are 16 bits wide and have integer values from 0 to 65535).  When you get the byte representation of a Java character, you have to tell the JVM the encoding you want to use so it will know how to choose the byte sequence for the character.

Answer (score 49):

## ASCII is fundamental

Originally 1 character was always stored as 1 byte. A byte (8 bits) has the potential to distinct 256 possible values. But in fact **only the first 7 bits were used**. So only 128 characters were defined. This set is known as **the ASCII character set**.

- `0x00` - `0x1F` contain steering codes (e.g. CR, LF, STX, ETX, EOT, BEL, ...)
- `0x20` - `0x40` contain numbers and punctuation
- `0x41` - `0x7F` contain mostly alphabetic characters
- `0x80` - `0xFF` the 8th bit = undefined.

French, German and many other languages needed additional characters. (e.g. `à, é, ç, ô, ...`) which were not available in the ASCII character set. So they used the 8th bit to define their  characters. This is what is known as "**extended ASCII**".

The problem is that the additional 1 bit has not enough capacity to cover all languages in the world. So each region has its own ASCII variant. There are many extended ASCII encodings (`latin-1` being a very popular one).

Popular question: ***"Is ASCII a character set or is it an encoding"*** ? `ASCII` is a character set. However, in programming `charset` and `encoding` are wildly used as synonyms. If I want to refer to an encoding that only contains the ASCII characters and nothing more (the 8th bit is always 0): that's `US-ASCII`.

## Unicode goes one step further

**[Unicode](https://nl.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unicode) is a great example of a character set - not an encoding**. It uses the same characters like the ASCII standard, but it extends the list with additional characters, which gives each character a codepoint in format `u+xxxx`. It has the ambition to contain all characters (and popular icons) used in the entire world.

**UTF-8, UTF-16 and UTF-32 are encodings that apply the Unicode character table.** But they each have a slightly different way on how to encode them. UTF-8 will only use 1 byte when encoding an ASCII character, giving the same output as any other ASCII encoding. But for other characters, it will use the first bit to indicate that a 2nd byte will follow.

**[GBK](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GBK) is an encoding, which just like UTF-8 uses multiple bytes.** The principle is pretty much the same. The first byte follows the ASCII standard, so only 7 bits are used. But just like with UTF-8, The 8th bit can be used to indicate the presence of a 2nd byte, which it then uses to encode one of 22,000 Chinese characters. The main difference, is that this **does not follow the Unicode character set**, by contrast it uses some Chinese character set.

## Decoding data

When you encode your data, you use an encoding, but when you decode data, you will need to know what encoding was used, and use that same encoding to decode it.

**Unfortunately, encodings aren't always declared or specified.** It would have been ideal if all files contained a prefix to indicate what encoding their data was stored in. But still in many cases applications just have to assume or guess what encoding they should use. (e.g. they use the standard encoding of the operating system).

**There still is a lack of awareness about this, as still many developers don't even know what an encoding is.**

## Mime types

Mime types are sometimes confused with encodings. They are a useful way for the receiver to identify what kind of data is arriving. Here is an example, of how the HTTP protocol defines it's content type using a mime type declaration.

```
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
```

And that's another great source of confusion. A mime type describes **what kind of data** a message contains (e.g. `text/xml`, `image/png`, ...). And in some cases it will additionally also describe **how** the data is encoded (i.e. `charset=utf-8`). 2 points of confusion:

1. Not all mime types declare an encoding. In some cases it is only optional or sometimes completely pointless.
2. The syntax `charset=utf-8` adds up to the semantic confusion, because as explained earlier, UTF-8 is an encoding and not a character set. But as explained earlier, some people just use the 2 words interchangeably.

For example, in the case of `text/xml` it would be pointless to declare an encoding (and a `charset` parameter would simply be ignored). Instead, **XML parsers in general will read the first line of the file, looking for the `<?xml encoding=...` tag.** If it's there, then they will reopen the file using that encoding.

The same problem exists [when sending e-mails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044027/utf-8-charset-doesnt-work-with-javax-mail/27404861#27404861). An e-mail can contain a html message or just plain text. Also in that case mime types are used to define the type of the content.

But in summary, a mime type isn't always sufficient to solve the problem.

## Data types in programming languages

In case of Java (and many other programming languages) in addition to the dangers of encodings, there's also the complexity of casting bytes and integers to characters because their content is stored in different ranges.

- a byte is stored as a signed byte (range: `-128` to `127`).
- the `char` type in java is stored in 2 unsigned bytes (range: `0` - `65535`)
- a stream returns an integer in range `-1` to `255`.

If you know that your data only contains ASCII values. Then with the proper skill you can parse your data from bytes to characters or wrap them immediately in Strings.

```
// the -1 indicates that there is no data
int input = stream.read();
if (input == -1) throw new EOFException();

// bytes must be made positive first.
byte myByte = (byte) input;
int unsignedInteger = myByte & 0xFF;
char ascii = (char)(unsignedInteger);
```

## Shortcuts

**The shortcut in java is to use readers and writers and to specify the encoding when you instantiate them.**

```
// wrap your stream in a reader. 
// specify the encoding
// The reader will decode the data for you
Reader reader = new InputStreamReader(inputStream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

As explained earlier for XML files it doesn't matter that much, because any decent DOM or JAXB marshaller will check for an encoding attribute.

Comment: Just a small note: 
Since almost all encodings encode the 128 basic ASCII characters in the same way, as long as all used characters are defined in this basic set, you can actually encode/decode your message using almost any random encoding. (e.g. UTF-8, US-ASCII, latin-1, GBK, ...).

Comment: Also interesting is the BOM (byte-order-mark) which is used for encodings that use multiple bytes (e.g. UTF-16). It indicates which of the bytes is the first one (most significant). This marker-byte is put in front of the message. Another good reason to use decent `Reader`s.

Comment: The character table of Unicode *is* an encoding by definition, nevertheless it is double-encoded in i. e. UTF-8. Therefore it is simply wrong, that Unicode has no encoding.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I did not write "unicode *has* no encoding". Unicode has encodings: (e.g. UTF-8, UTF-16, ... etc .) Bot those are implementations. Unicode itself is pretty much just like "the alphabet", it's just a list of characters. That's why Unicode *is not* an encoding. An encoding on the other hand should describe how the information will be stored in bits and bytes. - I have no idea what you mean by "double-encoded" though. Are you referring to the fact that there are multiple unicode implementations ? (because I do agree on that).

Comment: Unicode **is** an encoding itself. It maps symbols to code points. I. e. there are gaps in *Unicode* and this is not like a simple list, but a mapping. The Unicode itself maps "A" (latin capital letter A) to the **code** U+0041. And this Unicode then is again encoded into UTF-8. UTF-16 or whatever. Coding an symbol twice does not mean, that the first encoding isn't one. If it would be a simple list, UTF-8 wouldn't work, because it needs a number as input, not a symbol.

Comment: UTF-8 does not work on "". It works on 0x2F804. This is the *Unicode* of "".

Comment: Yes, it's a mapping, which in plain English is a **list** of characters and their codepoints. (i.e. a numbered list with gaps) Anyway, call it a "list", call it a "map", but to avoid confusion, just don't call it an "encoding" that's my point. Because Unicode and UTF-8 are not interchangeable. They are 2 different kind of things. In my vocabulary: mapping characters to codepoints is not an encoding, that's just a character set. - End of discussion (I really find discussions about semantics a huge waste of time).

Comment: A list can be unordered, unnumbered, … So it is a list with characters and code points, but no encoding? *In computing, a character encoding is used to represent a repertoire of characters by some kind of encoding system.* What you say is literally the definition of an encoding. – I've never said, that Unicode and UTF-8 are interchangeable. However, to use a wrong term or to use a term wrongly never reduces confusion, but boosts it. Wrong terms are the root of confusion. And this has something to do with definitions of terms, what of course is very important, if you want to reduce confusion.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad I added a new part to my answer which will hopefully enlighten you, so that you can finally understand this topic.

Comment: There is nothing to enlighten. I understood, what you said. But "1. A, 2. a, 3. B" *is an encoding itself* by the definition of what an encoding is. In your example two encodings are used: The letter to index map on the left and the index to "some data stored/transmitted/whatever" in the right. The left one encoding is Unicode, the right one UTF-8 (or UTF-16 or …) oin the discussion. (Of course not the real encoding.) BTW: If the data is stored or transmitted there might be another encoding for the (already) encoded data. Again this is an encoding.

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad oh well, then we have different definitions for the word "encoding". Mine happens to match the one of W3C though. ;-) https://www.w3.org/International/articles/definitions-characters/#charsets

Comment: No "A **coded** character set is a set of characters for which a unique number has been assigned to each character. " This is the same definition I used from wikipedia. ;-)

Comment: @AminNegm-Awad yes it's a coded character set, but that does not make it an "encoding", which is more like an algorithm. (I'm giving you a +1 for effort though).

Answer (score 4):

Character encoding is what you use to solve the problem of writing software for somebody who uses a different language than you do.

You don't know how what the characters are and how they are ordered. Therefore, you don't know what the strings in this new language will look like in binary and frankly, you don't care.

What you do have is a way of translating strings from the language you speak to the language they speak (say a translator). You now need a system that is capable of representing both languages in binary without conflicts. The encoding is that system.

It is what allows you to write software that works regardless of the way languages are represented in binary.

Answer (score 1):

Most computer programs must communicate with a person using some text in a natural language (a language used by humans). But computers have no fundamental means for representing text: the fundamental computer representation is a sequence of bits organized into bytes and words, with hardware support for interpreting sequences of bits as fixed width base-2 (binary) integers and floating-point real numbers. Computer programs must therefore have a scheme for representing text as sequences of bits. This is fundamentally what character encoding is. There is no inherently obvious or correct scheme for character encoding, and so there exist many possible character encodings.

However, practical character encodings have some shared characteristics.

1. Encoded texts are divided into a sequence of *characters* (graphemes).
2. Each of the known possible characters has an encoding. The encoding of a text consists of the sequence of the encoding of the characters of the text.
3. Each possible (allowed) character is assigned a unique unsigned (non negative) integer (this is sometimes called a *code point*). Texts are therefore encoded as a sequence of unsigned integers. Different character encodings differ in the characters they allow, and how they assign these unique integers. Most character encodings do not allow all the characters used by the many human writing systems (scripts) that do and have existed. Thus character encodings differ in which texts they can represent at all. Even character encodings that can represent the same text can represent it differently, because of their different assignment of code points.
4. The unsigned integer encoding a character is encoded as a sequence of bits. Character encodings differ in the number of bits they use for this encoding. When those bits are grouped into bytes (as is the case for popular encodings), character encodings can differ in endianess. Character encodings can differ in whether they are fixed width (the same number of bits for each encoded character) or variable width (using more bits for some characters).

Therefore, if a computer program receives a sequence of bytes that are meant to represent some text, the computer program **must** know the character encoding used for that text, if it is to do any kind of manipulation of that text (other than regarding it as an opaque value and forwarding it unchanged). The only possibilities are that the text is accompanied by additional data that indicates the encoding used *or* the program requires (assumes) that the text has a particular encoding.

Similarly, if a computer program must send (output) text to another program or a display device, it must either tell the destination the character encoding used *or* the program must use the encoding that the destination expects.

In practice, **almost all problems with character encodings** are caused when a destination expects text sent using one character encoding, and the text is actually sent with a different character encoding. That in turn is typically caused by the computer programmer not bearing in mind that there exist *many* possible character encodings, and that their program can not treat encoded text as opaque values, but must convert from an external representation on input and convert to an external representation on output.