# Can't print hindi characters

Tags: java

[image: Output_Screen]

```
public class demo {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for(int k = 2029; k<=2360 ; k++)
        {
            System.out.print(k+  " "+(char)k+" ");
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

`2029 ? 2030 ? 2031 ? 2032 ? 2033 ? 2034 ? 2035 ? 2036 ? 2037 ? 2038 ? 2039 ? 2040 ? 2041 ? 2042 ? 2043 ? 2044 ? 2045 ? 2046 ? 2047 ? 2048 ? 2049 ? 2050 ? 2051 ? 2052 ? 2053 ? 2054 ? 2055 ? 2056 ? 2057 ? 2058 ? 2059 ? 2060 ? 2061 ? 2062 ? 2063 ? 2064 ? 2065 ? 2066 ? 2067 ? 2068 ? 2069 ? 2070 ? and so on..`.

this output shows on cmd ...
why it not show hindi character ....

Comment: or how i print hindi character???

Comment: Make sure your console can interpret the output

Comment: The `?` you're seeing are because your console doesn't support those characters. Try showing them in a `JLabel` or `JOptionPane` instead.

Comment: i install the hindi font but again it show the same thing ....

Comment: Please include exactly where you are viewing the output (ex. cmd.exe on windows, bash on linux etc.)

Comment: i run this on console in eclipse

Comment: Unicode usually works OK

Comment: Is the console able to display hindi characters without the program? Try that first

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**In Eclipse:**

You need to change your Eclipse Console encoding to UTF-8. To do so, go into your **Run Configuration** dialog and select the **Common** tab. Under **Encoding**, choose `UTF-8`. Now run your program. You should see hindi characters printed in the Eclipse console.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem when running your program under Intellij.  I fixed by changing the debug command line from

-Dfile.encoding=windows-1251 to -Dfile.encoding=utf-8

Intellij set the default file encoding to a value that would not work for Hindi.  My eclipse is rusty, but see if you can change the vm options for the debugger to -Dfile.encoding=utf-8

Answer (score 2):

Eclipse has in-built unicode editor if you create a file say .properties file for internationalization.
If you enable under RUN Configuration Common tab. Under Console Encoding=>Other select UTF-8. 
Then console will read it in your choice language. Still you need to provide unicode characters to your file, or you convert your characters to UNICODE.

Now if you have character of your language say here in hindi विमल कृष्णा (In need these characters by some editor) then if i just paste in eclipse .properties file, it will be automatically converted to \u0935\u093F\u092E\u0932 \u0915\u0943\u0937\u094D\u0923\u093E.

Above string will be now interpreted as विमल कृष्णा in the console.

Example:
Step 1
In Spring you need in classpath(say inside src/main/resources) under a folder called 'locale' a file named

**messages_hi_IN.properties** (for hindi) with content

```
user.name=\u0935\u093F\u092E\u0932 \u0915\u0943\u0937\u094D\u0923\u093E, age : {0}, URL : {1}
```

**messages_en_US.properties** (for English) with content

```
user.name=vimal krishna, age : {0}, URL : {1}
```

Step 2:

you main Application:

```
package com.vimal.common;

import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;
import java.util.Locale;

 import org.springframework.context.ApplicationContext;
 import org.springframework.context.support.ClassPathXmlApplicationContext;

 public class App {
      public static void main(String[] args) {

       ApplicationContext context 
        = new ClassPathXmlApplicationContext("com/vimal/common/beans.xml");

       String name = context.getMessage("user.name", new Object[] { 45,"http://www.vkrishna.com" }, Locale.US);

    System.out.println("User name (English) : " + name);

    String nameHindi = context.getMessage("user.name", new Object[] {45, "http://www.vkrishna.com" }, new Locale("hi", "IN"));

    System.out.println("User name (Hindi) : " + nameHindi);

  }
}
```

Step 3: The Configuration file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans      
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd">

<bean id="messageSource"
    class="org.springframework.context.support.ResourceBundleMessageSource">
    <property name="basename">
        <value>locale\messages</value>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Here **locale** is the folder inside src/main/resources which is on the class path (if a maven project is created by eclipse) inside which messages_hi_IN.properties file is located. locale\messages refers to this **messages**_hi_IN.properties files, adding hi_IN is key for locale detection for hindi.
Now in main application you can see a  new Locale("hi", "IN") is created as it is not defined in eclipse like locale.US and others.

RESULT will be :

```
Dez 31, 2014 12:19:12 PM org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory preInstantiateSingletons
INFORMATION: Pre-instantiating singletons in   org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory@5594a1b5: defining beans [messageSource]; root of factory hierarchy
Customer name (English) : vimal krishna, age : 45, URL : http://www.vkrishna.com
Customer name (Hindi) : विमल कृष्णा, age : ४५, URL : http://www.vkrishna.com
```

I have reworked the [link...](http://www.mkyong.com/spring/spring-resource-bundle-with-resourcebundlemessagesource-example/)

Comment: Same is not working on server when i print in logger its showing as ???? ???! for प्रिय मेंबर, मुबारक हो!