# How to allow internationals words in a string

Tags: java, utf

I need to allow internationals words in our string.

For example:

```
public class Java
{
    public static void main (String[] args) throws Exception
    {
        String a="ğğğğ";
        System.out.println(a);
    }
}
```

The expected output is:

> ğğğğ

but I get:

> ????

instead.

Comment: those glyph must be at elast in one familyfont in the OS you are running the code... did you check that??

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34987954/why-this-code-always-produce-output-as

Comment: The String is storing those characters, but it doesn't mean you can print them on your console.

Comment: Can any one help me with the command to print the same keywords given as input ?

Answer (score 0):

Since String objects in Java don't have an encoding, and only byte arrays can support different encodings. Looks like you want to work on UTF-8 data, which you can do using byte arrays.

Try converting your String to byte[] with desired encoding, and then reconstruct your String.