# How to send email with non-english sender ID in Java?

Tags: java, email, jakarta-mail

I want to send email from non-english email ID like डेमो@डेमो.कॉम to any email ID 
using java.

When I use :

```
String to = "demo@gmail.com";
 String from = "डेमो@डेमो.कॉम";

      String host = "localhost";

      Properties properties = System.getProperties();
          properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

      Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

      try{
         // Create a default MimeMessage object.
         MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

         message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


         message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                                  new InternetAddress(to));

         message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

         // Now set the actual message
         message.setText("This is actual message");

         Transport.send(message);
         System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
      }catch (MessagingException mex) {
         mex.printStackTrace();
      }
```

It throw exception like :

```
javax.mail.SendFailedException: Sending failed;
  nested exception is:
    class javax.mail.MessagingException: 501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

    at javax.mail.Transport.send0(Transport.java:218)
    at javax.mail.Transport.send(Transport.java:80)
    at com.data.TestingSendMail.main(TestingSendMail.java:49)
```

Please suggest me what I need do for it.

Comment: try `message.setHeader("Content-Type", "text/plain; charset=UTF-8");`

Comment: @singhakash its not working too

Answer (score 0):

What you should do is add the encoding format:

```
String to = "demo@gmail.com";
String from = "डेमो@डेमो.कॉम";

String host = "localhost";

Properties properties = System.getProperties();
    properties.setProperty("mail.smtp.host", host);

Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(properties);

try{
   // Create a default MimeMessage object.
   MimeMessage message = new MimeMessage(session);

   message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));


   message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO,
                            new InternetAddress(to));

   message.setSubject("This is the Subject Line!");

   message.setText("This is actual message","UTF-8");

   Transport.send(message);
   System.out.println("Sent message successfully....");
}catch (MessagingException mex) {
   mex.printStackTrace();
}
```

When you set an encode in the `.setText` method you also tell the header encoding.

Comment: You could also check [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044027/utf-8-charset-doesnt-work-with-javax-mail) and this [other post](http://www.coderanch.com/t/603839/java/java/sending-english-characters-Java-Mail)

Comment: I know the UTF-8 working for setText() but it used for non-english body message. And my problem is that sender email id is in hindi or any other non-english language.

Comment: If you're interested in testing a version of JavaMail 1.6.0 with this support, please contact me at javamail_ww@oracle.com.

Answer (score 0):

First you need a complete from adress (including domain part). If your domain also contains international characters, you need to convert it 
to Punycode using [java.net.IDN.toASCII](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/net/IDN.html#toASCII-java.lang.String-) like this:

```
String[] emailSplit = from.split("@");
String local = emailSplit[0];
String domain = emailSplit[1];
String punycodeDomain = java.net.IDN.toASCII(domain);
String newEmail = local + "@" + punycodeDomain;
```

(simplified version, some error checking required)

Comment: it showing same error.:501 Syntax error in parameters or arguments

Comment: Taking a closer look your from adress is not complete, it does not contain an "@" char. My answer assumed that you use international domain names.