# How to encode Japanese characters javamail

Tags: java, jakarta-mail, encode

So basically I'm trying to send an email with Japanese characters, something like "" and then I got "???" what should I do to encode this? I have looked over a bunch of solutions but none of them have helped me solve this.

here's the method I've been trying to do the encode:

```
public String encoding(String str) throws UnsupportedEncodingException{
  String Encoding = "Shift_JIS";
  return this.changeCharset(str, Encoding);
}
public String changeCharset(String str, String newCharset) throws UnsupportedEncodingException {
  if (str != null) {
    byte[] jis = str.getBytes("Shift_JIS");
    return new String(bs, newCharset);
  }
  return null;
}
```

Comment: A bit similar to [check this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044027/utf-8-charset-doesnt-work-with-javax-mail). probably something wrong with charset.

Comment: How are you sending the email?  Plain text or HTML?  Are you specifying the character encoding in the email? Your problem might be that your email client does not know what character set to use.  You most likely do not need to use Shift_JIS, you can almost certainly use UTF-8 or UTF-16.

Comment: Also, your changeCharset doesn't seem to make sense.  You seem to be attempting to read the bytes from the input string as Shift_JIS, and then convert them to Shift_JIS on the output.  The only place you need to specify the encoding is when you are attaching the bytes to the email.  That is when you would call `getBytes("Shift_JIS")` and attach the byte array result to the email.

Comment: I'm using this to set the html part to be sent   MimeBodyPart htmlPart = new MimeBodyPart();
        htmlPart.setContent(encoding(mailMessage.getMessageHTML()), "text/html"); Jamie

Comment: I have already checked the link Viroj, but still does not work

Answer (score 0):

You're making this too complicated...

First, make sure you have the Japanese text in a proper Java String object, using proper Unicode characters.

Then, set the content of the body part using [this method](https://javaee.github.io/javamail/docs/api/javax/mail/internet/MimeBodyPart.html#setText-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-java.lang.String-):

```
htmlPart.setText(japaneseString, "Shift_JIS", "html");
```