# Spring Integration Email outbound gateway: how to set content encoding as UTF-8?

Tags: email, spring-integration

Is there any ways to set email's encoding in XML configuration?
I just use XML email support: int-mail:outbound-channel-adapter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See this SO thread for similar discussion : [UTF-8 charset doesn't work with javax.mail](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15044027/utf-8-charset-doesnt-work-with-javax-mail)

There is also a `MailHeaders.CONTENT_TYPE` header you can send in the request message - with the value the same as it is explained in the SO thread above.