# Convert 16 bits in memory into std::string

Tags: c++, string, unicode, stdstring, wchar

I'm getting 16 bits from a struct in memory, and I need to convert them into a string. The 16 bits represent a unicode char:

```
typedef struct my_struct {
    unsigned    unicode     : 16;
} my_struct;
```

I started by casting the bits into an unsigned char, which worked for values small enough to fit in one char. However, for characters like '♪', it truncates incorrectly. This is what I have so far:

```
        char buffer[2] = { 0 };
        wchar_t wc[1] = { 0 };

        wc[0] = page->text[index].unicode;
        std::cout << wc[0] << std::endl; //PRINT LINE 1
        int ret = wcstombs(buffer, wc, sizeof(buffer));
        if(ret < 0)
            printf("SOMETHING WENT WRONG \n");
        std::string my_string(buffer);
        printf("%s \n", my_string.c_str()); //PRINT LINE 2
```

Print line 1 currently prints: "9834" and print line 2 prints: "" (empty string). I'm trying to get my_string to contain '♪'.

Comment: You can't fit 16 bits into 8 bits without losing something. Your choices are to convert from (apparently) UTF-16 to UTF-8 (uses multiple 8-bit characters to hold one 16-bit code unit) or leave it in UTF-16 (e.g., `std::wstring` holds units of `wchar_t`, which *may* be UTF-16). If neither of those works, you could instantiate `std::basic_string` over your `my_struct` directly: `std::basic_string<my_struct> whatever;`

Comment: You can't put 16 pounds of flour in a 8 pound sack.

Comment: You can't fit 16 bits in an 8-bit `char`. Why do you think you need to? Perhaps just put it into a `wchar_t` (or `std::wstring`).

Comment: I'm not trying to put it in a 8-bit char. I'm trying to get it in a std::string.

Comment: @mirandak `std::string` is a typedef for `std::basic_string<char>`. It holds 8-bit chars (assuming your platform has 8-bit chars, of course).

Comment: @mirandak A `std::string` normally contains a sequence of 8 bit characters.

Comment: I'm confused because I can do this and have the music note print correctly:
            std::string s("\u266A");
           printf("%s\n", s.c_str());
Basically, I'm trying to get there with the "266A" value alone.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: a bit pedantic, but std::*string doesn't store (or care about) character encoding. Even if wchar_t is 16-bit, it could be UCS-2. In general, you want either UCS-4 or UTF-8. UTF-16 combines disadvantages of both with no gain.

Comment: @DanielKO: I certainly wouldn't recommend UTF-16 as a general rule -- that's simply reflecting the OP's use of 16 bits. UCS-2 has been [obsolete](http://www.unicode.org/faq/basic_q.html#14) for a *long* time now.

Comment: @JerryCoffin I didn't write the library that's giving me it in UCS-2! Not my fault haha

Comment: @mirandak: Unless the library is really old (and hasn't been updated within the last decade or so) it's probably UTF-16 rather than UCS-2.

Comment: @Jerry Coffin: only the first sentence was directed at you. Still, if the input contains only a single 16-bit value, it can't be UTF-16, as it is variable-length. If it's a single 16-bit value, then it's either truncated UTF-16 (which can be useless) or UCS-2.

Comment: @JerryCoffin http://zapping.sourceforge.net/doc/libzvbi/structvbi__char.html#b24b2927ec57213d9d8cc667b439965f

Comment: @mirandak: Apparently I should add "or written by a lunatic" to the previous guess. :-)

Comment: I would run away from any library that hardcodes "unicode" to be 16-bit. There is even a note there saying it is not even using real UCS-2 because of its limited representation, and arbitrarily remapping some special ranges.

Comment: @DanielKO At least in the usual implementations under Unix or Windows, `std::string` _cannot_ store UTF-16; at the very least, it would have to be UTF-16LE or  UTF-16BE.

Comment: @JerryCoffin It depends.  UTF-16 is just as good as UTF-32 if you only have to deal with European languages, or are only interested in specific characters.  (On the other hand, if he wants musical symbols, most will require two code points in UTF-16, as they're in the range `'\U0001D100'`--`'\U0001D1FF'`.)

Comment: If you only have to deal with one specific codepage, just stick with the old iso 8859-* codepages and have an application that is not unicode-aware. If you are going to claim to support unicode, either you actually support unicode or not. "Broken unicode" is worse than the old locale-based encodings.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I've done my conversion correctly, 0x9834 in UTF-16 (16 bit
Unicode) translates to the three byte sequence 0xE9, 0xA0,
0xB4 in UTF-8 (8 bit Unicode).  I don't know about other narrow
byte encodings, but I doubt any would be shorter than 2 bytes.
You pass a buffer of two bytes to `wcstombs`, which means
a returned string of at most 1 bytes.  `wcstombs` stops
translating (without failing!) when there's no more room in the
destination buffer.  You've also failed to `L'\0'` terminate the
input buffer.  It's not a problem at the moment, because
`wcstombs` will stop translating before it gets there, but you
should normally add the extra `L'\0'`.

So what to do:

First, and formost, when debugging this sort of thing, look at
the return value of `wcstombs`.  I'll bet that it's `0`, because
of the lack of space.

Second, I'd give myself a little bit of margin.  Legal Unicode
can result in up to four bytes in UTF-8, so I'd allocate at
least 5 bytes for the output (don't forget the trailing `'\0'`).
Along the same lines, you need a trailing `L'\0'` for the input.
So:

```
char buffer[ 5 ];
wchar_t wc[] = { page->text[index].unicode, L'\0' };
int ret = wcstombs( buffer, wc, sizeof( buffer ) );
if ( ret < 1 ) {    //  And *not* 0
    std::cerr << "OOPS\n";
}
std::string str( buffer, buffer + ret );
std::cout << str << '\n';
```

Of course, after all that, there is still the question of what
the (final) display device does with UTF-8 (or whatever the
multi-byte narrow character encoding is---UTF-8 is almost
universal under Unix, but I'm not sure about Windows.)  But
since you say that displaying `"\u9834"` seems to work, it
should be alright.

Comment: The Windows console can display UTf-8 _in theory_, but getting it to actually do so is tricky.

Comment: I know you can't peer into my computer, but with this code wcstombs is returns -1 once a char with value > 127 comes up.

**edit:** err not a char but you know what i mean

Comment: Think it was a locale issue, because I slapped "setlocale(LC_ALL, "");" in there and it suddenly worked! Now to figure out what locale I actually need... But thanks!!!

Comment: The 9834 value from the question appears to be decimal.  The music note shown is U+266A (which happens to be hexadecimal for 9834).

Comment: @MooingDuck So I've heard.  I've only tried it once or twice, and it seemed to work (using code page 65001), but that was for very simple things.

Comment: @mirandak Yes.  `wcstombs` is locale sensitive, and will probably _not_ translate characters greater than 127 in the default `"C"` locale.  I should have mentioned that.  (But the fact that you didn't mention getting an error from it, and that you could display `"\9834"` led me to believe that you had these aspects sorted out.)

Comment: @AdrianMcCarthy Ah.  I'm just so used to seeing hexadecimal used here.  (And I don't know why, I misread his statement about printing `"9834"`, which led me to believe that he had successfully solved the locale and code page issues.)  Still, it doesn't really matter: if he wants to convert UTF-16, he needs a sufficiently large buffer, and he needs to pass `wcstombs` a `L'\0'` terminated string, so my answer is still correct, as far as it goes, even if I didn't fully understand the point he was at.

Answer (score 1):

Please read a bit about what "character encoding" means, like this: [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding)

Then figure out what encoding you are getting in, and what encoding you need to use on the output. That means figuring out what your file format / GUI library / console is expecting.

Then use something reliable like libiconv to convert between them, instead of the so-implementation-defined-that-is-almost-useless wcstombs()+wchar_t.

For example, you might find that your input is UCS-2, and you need to output it into UTF-8. My system has 32-bit wchar_t, I wouldn't count on it converting from UCS-2 to UTF-8.

Answer (score 1):

To convert from UTF-16 to UTF-8, use `codecvt_utf8<char16_t>`:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <locale>
#include <codecvt>

int main() {
    char16_t wstr16[2] = {0x266A, 0};
    auto conv = std::wstring_convert<std::codecvt_utf8_utf16<char16_t>, char16_t>{};
    auto u8str = std::string{conv.to_bytes(wstr16)};
    std::cout << u8str << '\n';
}
```

Comment: What's the point of `auto u8str = std::string{ conv.to_bytes( wstr16 ) };`, rather than `std::string u8str( conv.to_bytes( wstr16 ) );`, except maybe obfuscation?

Comment: @JamesKanze it's AAA style: http://herbsutter.com/2013/06/13/gotw-94-special-edition-aaa-style-almost-always-auto/

Comment: @mirandak you're using embedded Unicode codepoints in your comment `std::string s("\u266A"); `, which are a C++11 feature.

Comment: @ecatmur Another anti-pattern.  If you don't want to name the types, use Python.  But except in a few particular cases, you _do_ want to name the type, so that the reader has some idea of what is going on.  AAA is just bad engineering.

Comment: @ecatmur They're in my copy of the C++98 standard (and in C90 as well).