# Java byte[] to String not working when assigned to String

Tags: java, string, arrays, apache-kafka

I am using Kafka and following along with this tutorial (https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Consumer+Group+Example)

After some tweaks, the code compiles and everything runs like it should. my problem is that I am trying to utilize an array of bytes that the Kafka server sends me to do some processing. If I use the default code, everything works fine and the byte array gets converted to a String and displayed on my screen. If I try to read the byte array and assign it to a String so that I can display it to the screen and then parse it nothing happens.

> it.next().message() returns a byte array

Default code:

```
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
while (it.hasNext())
    System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + new String(it.next().message()));
```

My Code that breaks:

```
 ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
 String msg= "";
 while (it.hasNext())
    msg = new String(it.next().message());
    System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + msg);
```

Can anybody tell me why I cannot assign the byte array to my String? And of course how to fix my glitch?

I've taken a look at:

[Java byte to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20112935/java-byte-to-string)

[Convert byte to string in Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8654141/convert-byte-to-string-in-java)

[converting byte[] to string](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9309899/converting-byte-to-string)

but none of them seem to apply, they all try to assign the byte array to the String as the String is initialized and I cannot do that here.

Comment: What error message are you getting?

Comment: Also, why don't you have braces around your while-loop?

Comment: no error message. nothing at all is displayed to the screen

Comment: Please describe the problem more precisely than "it breaks"

Comment: `{` and `}` are your friends

Comment: OK well there it is I have been sitting at my desk too long. The default code only executes that one line so I didn't need the brackets. When I added the extra line I violated that assumption of a while one liner. Credit to @Juan as having the first answer when I checked in (and honestly I owe you an apology because I scoffed at it. Sorry for the ill thoughts about your reply) I'll accept it as soon as SO will let me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are missing the curly brackets so your println is only being executed the last time. Try this:

```
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
String msg= "";
while (it.hasNext())
{
   msg = new String(it.next().message());
   System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + msg);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code is failing because you did not enclose your code block in braces. Adjusting your code reveals:

```
ConsumerIterator<byte[], byte[]> it = m_stream.iterator();
while (it.hasNext()) { // <- here
    String msg = new String(it.next().message());
    System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + msg);
} // <- and here
```

In fact, with these braces this code snippet is equivalent to your first code snippet.

By the way: No need to declare the variable `msg` outside the loop.

Answer (score 0):

Just put curly braces while loop block.

```
while (it.hasNext()){msg = new String(it.next().message());
System.out.println("Thread " + m_threadNumber + ": " + msg);}
```