# Encoding utf-8 doesn't recognize text

Tags: encoding, utf-8, terminal

Terminal: screen in xterm on the latest Ubuntu LiveCD.

��� �������.avi

While I'm trying to `ls` directory, I see this: [image: a]

`ls -la` give me this: [image: b]

MidNight Commander show me this: [image: c]

```
$ ls
??? ???????.avi

$ env | grep -i LANG
LANG=en_US.UTF-8

$ export | grep -i LANG
declare -x LANG="en_US.UTF-8"
```

Looks like this is [UTF-16 surrogate](http://www.unicode.org/faq/utf_bom.html#utf8-5), am I right? [

en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mapping_of_Unicode_characters#Surrogates

I'm trying to trick it through **python3**, I'm caught such exception:

```
for i in os.listdir('.'):
    print (i)
UnicodeEncodeError: 'utf-8' codec can't encode character '\udcc4' in
position 0: surrogates not allowed
```

I've uploaded file with empty body, just title - 4.0K: https://mega.co.nz/#!roYUyQaB!AwOMDznj9DC_wSpAeWqjVj_Oqu2z8Kfk5VsSmFs0ybA

Comment: It is possible for the file system to contain byte sequences which are not valid UTF-8, that's right.  It's an error to use that in a file name on a file system set up for UTF-8 file names.  What is unclear?  If you need a workaround, remount the file system with a suitable encoding for such file names (the sequence would be valid, albeit gibberish, in many legacy 8-bit encodings, for example).

Comment: @tripleee, see my edit. Could you download this file and recognize it for me? What is it? Is it surrogate or what?

Comment: Why does it matter? Which particular problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: I'm trying to configure my terminal for the future, to prevent any unrecognizable filenames

Comment: Most real-life Unicode encodings will have the possibility of invalid code sequences in file names. Just rename the problematic files.

Comment: I'm doing this for a long time. When you have great p2p exchange network, such files appears each week/days. I don't feel this is True-Way(Unix-Way), to rename such files each times.

Comment: @tripleee, your  reputation 28,942. Do you know any universal way to decode anything by default in terminal? I'm just tired to meet such filenames.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$ echo $'\xc4\xf3\xf5 \xe2\xf0\xe5\xec\xe5\xed\xed' | chardet
<stdin>: MacCyrillic (confidence: 0.92)
$ echo $'\xc4\xf3\xf5 \xe2\xf0\xe5\xec\xe5\xed\xed' | enca -L ru
MS-Windows code page 1251
  LF line terminators
$ echo $'\xc4\xf3\xf5 \xe2\xf0\xe5\xec\xe5\xed\xe8' | iconv -f 'Windows-1251'
Дух времени
```

So you need to set your terminal to Windows-1251.