# Java - Writing to a file as text or as binary

Tags: java, stream, buffered

I have a question about using streams with files. I know that if I need to do my own file type then the best option is to write/read in binary using for example BufferedInput/Ouput streams. I have always been considering the best performance in my program so now I am curious about writing/reading strings. I have been using Writer and Reader classes with BufferedReader/Writer streams. I have been asking myself If it worths to write/read strings in binary format. 
I think there might be some performance boost but is this boost noteworthy?

Thank you for your answers.

Comment: What does writing strings in "a binary format" mean?

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it

Comment: It means writing text (chars) in binary form by usin String.getBytes()

Answer (score 0):

If you are reading/writings lines of characters, continue to use the Buffered reader/writer.

Quoting the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/BufferedReader.html):

> **Class BufferedReader**... Reads text from a character-input stream, buffering characters so as
>   to provide for the **efficient reading of characters, arrays, and lines**.