# Name containing character like "Â" is getting written with filewriter to csv. How to remove them with java?

Tags: java, encoding, character-encoding

When I create a csv file through java then for name "Men's Commemorative ® ELITE Bib Short", it is storing "Men's Commemorative Â® ELITE Bib Short" in csv. So I have to remove "Â" from csv file through java file.

```
public boolean writeProductsToFile()
{
    final List<ProductModel> products = getListrakDao().getProducts();

    final String filePath = getFilePath() + getProductFileName();
    final File file = new File(filePath);
    FileWriter writer = null;
    writer = new FileWriter(file);
    for (final ProductModel productModel : products)
    {
            productData.append(StringEscapeUtils.unescapeHtml("\"" + productModel.getName() + "\""));
            productData.append(getFieldSeparator());
            writer.write(productData.toString());
    }
}
```

This is my code...where "baseProduct.getName()" is fetching name of product.
In database product name is "Men's Commemorative ® ELITE Bib Short". But in csv it is getting written as "Men's Commemorative Â® ELITE Bib Short". So how can I remove characters like "Â". So tha#t name in csv should be like exactly in database.

Comment: can you please show us your effort?

Comment: In my opinion you should not try to remove the bad character in the resulting file but find the reason why it is written to the file in first place (and deal with that behaviour properly)

Comment: I have edited my question.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Comment: [No excuses!](http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html)

Comment: @Raedwald Just realised, you commented with the same article on the very question you just linked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To a degree, this is a shot in the dark, but...

As a general practice, try to be explicit with the character sets you use.

Instead of

```
FileWriter writer = null;
writer = new FileWriter(file);
```

write

```
final Charset utf8 = java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets.UTF_8;
final Writer writer = new OutputStreamWriter(new FileOutputStream(file), utf8);
```

(imports left out for brevity, `StandardCharsets` requires Java 7 or later)

This allows actively controlling the used charset when writing. If not set, the system uses the default charset, which may not be appropriate. If UTF-8 is not what you desire, try something else, like `ISO_8859_1`.

When you read your CSV file, make sure the reader/editor you use supports the used charset *and uses it*. Otherwise, you'll see strange characters, much like you did.

Comment: When I am doing this. This is giving me error : The constructor FileOutputStream(File, Charset) is undefined.

Comment: @pnegi Did my answer solve your problem? If so, please accept the answer. Thank you.