# Java Create String From Byte Array Including Spaces

Tags: java, arrays, string

I ran into an issue when creating a String from a byte array where values of 0 inside the array are ignored when constructing the string. How can I make it so that if the byte value is 0, the String simply adds a space instead of removing it.

Example, the output of this is `DT_TestTracelineCTestTraceli`.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    byte[] text = {68, 84, 95, 84, 101, 115, 116, 84, 114, 97, 99, 101, 108, 105, 110, 101, 0, 0, 0, 0, 67, 84, 101, 115, 116, 84, 114, 97, 99, 101, 108, 105};
    System.out.println(new String(text));
}
```

How can I make it so I can separate those two strings using a tab character or uses spaces so the output is `DT_TestTraceline    CTestTraceli`

Thanks

Comment: I believe you should also tell us which _encoding_ you are using to decode the byte array.

Comment: I'm reading the bytes from memory directly into a byte array.

Comment: I tested the code the output is: DT_TestTraceline    CTestTraceli

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should be specifying an encoding to `new String()` - Without one, you're using the platform default (which makes your code much less portable, as now you're making assumptions about the environment you're executing on).

Assuming you're using UTF-8, you can replace all of your zeroes with `32`, the UTF-8 code for the space character, and it should work:

```
for(int i = 0; i < text.length; i++) {
    if(text[i] == 0) {
        text[i] = 32; 
    }
}
String result = new String(text, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

You can see it working [on ideone](http://ideone.com/yd6TMk).

Answer (score 4):

One way would be to iterate over the array before turning it into a string and replacing '0' characters with the character code for space in whatever character encoding you are using