# Error in reading umlaut characters from csv file using spring batch

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I am using spring batch to read a csv file and write it to sql server.I am getting format error while reading.The string 'MRC DE LA HAUTE-CßTE-NORD' is read as 'MRC DE LA HAUTE-Cï¿½TE-NORD' and stored as 'MRC DE LA HAUTE-C?TE-NORD' in sql server.

kindly help.

Comment: See if you can specify a character encoding for the import (for reading the file).

Comment: I am sure you can. Check your code for a parameter to set the encoding.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)