# Getting "java.nio.charset.UnmappableCharacterException: Input length = 1"

Tags: java, java-8

I am getting UnmappableCharacterException on the collect() method call (or on the toList() call):

```
    private static void handleTransaction(Path a_filePath, String a_sTrasactionName, String a_sTransactionFilePath) {

    // read file into stream, try-with-resources
    try (Stream<String> stream = Files.lines(Paths.get(a_filePath.toString()), Charset.defaultCharset())) {

        List<String> list =
            stream.filter(line -> (line.indexOf(a_sTrasactionName) > 0))
            .collect(Collectors.toList());

        list.forEach(line -> {

            System.out.println(line);

            try (BufferedWriter writer = Files.newBufferedWriter(Paths.get(_FILES_PATH + a_sTransactionFilePath),Charset.defaultCharset(), StandardOpenOption.APPEND)) {
                writer.write(line + "\n");
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        });
    } catch (IOException e1) {

        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
```

It worked for me once, but never since then.

The files I read are csv files which were created on solaris. I run the jar on Windows 2012 server

Can you advise please?

Thank you.

Comment: Don’t use `Charset.defaultCharset()` if you already know that the files stem from a different system, most likely having a different charset. I’d be very surprised if a software on Solaris creates files in one of the Window encodings.

Comment: @Holger So, what should I put there as charset?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it)

Comment: @Raedwald Can you please remive your alert? The post you presented explaines about encoding in general, but does not help me about the exception. Thank you

Comment: Nope. Edit your question to indicate why it is not a duplicate of that canonical question. The heart of your problem is that you have not carefully selected your character encoding, relying on the defaults, which is a *very strong clue* that you do not understand the importance of character encoding

Comment: @Raedwald Again, I think I understand what is encoding quite well. And it seems that the file was created on Solaris with a different encoding from the one used on my windows machine. And this is what's probably causes the exception. The help that I need is how to overcome this exception? I also searched for Solaris encoding which seems to be Cp1252, but it didn't help me (or at leaset I was not using it properly).

Comment: Is there a way to determine the encoding of a file, so that Scala can continue executing the writer's code?

Answer (score 7):

> The files I read are csv files which were created on solaris. I run the jar on Windows 2012 server

Well that's probably the problem then. You're using the platform-default encoding for both reading and writing the file. If the files were created on Solaris, that may very well have a different platform-default encoding to your Windows box.

If you know the encoding of the file you're reading, specify that.

If you get to *control* the encoding of the file you're reading and writing, I would strongly recommend using UTF-8 unless you have a really good reason not to.

*Only* use `Charset.default()` if you're reading a file which you *know* uses the platform-default encoding, or if you're writing a file which you definitely *want* to use the platform-default encoding - and try to avoid the latter.

(Basically, a world where everything is encoded in UTF-8 is a simpler world...)

Comment: Is there a way I can enforce the file to be utf-8?

Comment: @dushkin: It's unclear what you mean. A file is just a sequence of bytes, basically. Anything which is able to create a file can create whatever sequence it wants. We have no idea what's creating the input file to start with... you should be looking at that to start with.

Comment: Amen on the UTF-8.  Use StandardCharsets.UTF_8 when you read the data.  I think we should sunset the other character sets, and deprecate them.

Answer (score 3):

Honestly, I'm not even sure if this is an answer, but I'd like to help. I'm having the same problem and used:

```
val source = io.Source.fromFile("C:/mon_usatotaldat.csv").codec.decodingReplaceWith("UTF-8")
```

And I got the output:

> source: scala.io.Codec = windows-1252

Comment: I was facing same issue in pom.xml file. Its surely encoding issue.  I added following line on top of pom.xml file and error gone : <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>