# How to convert string into byte array and write into text file?

Tags: c#, encoding

There is a question regarding the encoding as in [What is character encoding and why should I bother with it](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it). However, I still confuse with the encoding for the Windows system and file.

As I am working C# program on Visual Studio 2017, may I know how to convert the *string that is input in the textbox* to *byte array* and *write it into a text file*?

I am not writing the text to file is because I need the bytes value of the string as compression. For example:

Input : hello world

Bytes array that write to file: 罴讵8?瘈

Thank you for your time!

Comment: Why don't you write the text into the file, instead of the byte array?

Comment: @RuiJarimba Because I need the bytes for other conversion

Comment: Your last comment is not understandable. What do you **really** mean when saying "_I need the bytes for other conversion_"? Please explain more in detail. It is probably also a good idea to add an example of a short text and how the byte values should look like in the file.( Edit and improve your question, don't write a comment here.) Because, right now (and probably also in the end), the answer to your question here would _still_ be: Just write the text to the file...

Comment: `Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(<string>)` will get you the UTF8 bytes, use a different encoding if you need to

Comment: (o.O)???  `趟%觍` are not byte values (a byte has a numerical value between 0 and 255). These are just Chinese characters. Are you asking how to translate English to Chinese? Because if so, this is not about text encoding or byte values/arrays at all. You would need a language translation software with an English->Chinese dictionary to do that...

Comment: @elgonzo that is the content of file that shown in Notepad

Answer (score 2):

Convert to UTF-8 byte array

```
var byteArray = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(mystring);
```

Convert to UTF-8 string

```
var utf8string = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetString(byteArray);
```

Write UTF-8 byte array to file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes("from-bytearray.txt", byteArray);
```

Write string to file

```
System.IO.File.WriteAllText("from-string.txt", utf8string, Encoding.UTF8);
```

Comment: I have try this way but the output be like N層? . As it is different from the source I refer to, therefore, i wonder about whether is it encoding issue.