# Weird character not exists in html source python BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup, python-requests

I have watched a video that teaches how to use BeautifulSoup and requests to scrape a website
Here's the code

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

pages_to_scrape = 1

for i in range(1,pages_to_scrape+1):
    url = ('http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html').format(i)
    pages.append(url)
for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = bs4(page.text, 'html.parser')
    #print(soup.prettify())
for j in soup.findAll('p', class_='price_color'):
    price=j.getText()
    print(price)
```

The code i working well. But as for the results I noticed weird character before the euro symbol and when checking the html source, I didn't find that character. Any ideas why this character appears? and how this be fixed .. is using replace enough or there is a better approach?

Comment: Sounds like you don't understand character sets, and are looking at UTF-8 with some legacy character set enabled, like maybe Windows code page 1251.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10611455/what-is-character-encoding-and-why-should-i-bother-with-it; see also https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/379403/problematic-questions-about-decoding-errors

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems for me you explained your question wrongly. I assume that you are using Windows where your terminal IDLE is using the default encoding of `cp1252`,

But you are dealing with `UTF-8`, you've to configure your terminal/IDLE with `UTF-8`

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


def main(url):
    with requests.Session() as req:
        for item in range(1, 10):
            r = req.get(url.format(item))
            print(r.url)
            soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, 'html.parser')
            goal = [(x.h3.a.text, x.select_one("p.price_color").text)
                    for x in soup.select("li.col-xs-6")]
            print(goal)


main("http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html")
```

1. try to always use `The DRY Principle` which means [Don’t Repeat Yourself”](https://realpython.com/lessons/dry-principle/).
2. Since you are dealing with the same `host` so you've to maintain the same session instead of keep open `tcp` socket stream and then close it and then open it again. That's can lead to block your requests and consider it as `DDOS` attack where the `TCP` flags got captured by the back-end. *imagine that you open your browser and then open a website then you close it and repeat the circle!*
3. Python `functions` is usually looks nice and easy to read instead of letting code looks like journal text.

> Notes: the usage of `range()` and `{}` format string, `CSS` selectors.

Comment: How can I extract the number of stars which is attribute? I tried to modify the code you have posted like that `(x.h3.a.text, x.select_one("p.price_color").text, x.select_one("p.star-rating").attrs.items())` but I didn't get it. I know it is wrong but how can I get the attribute value?

Comment: I can get in the result as for stars `dict_items([('class', ['star-rating', 'Three'])])`. How can I get `Three` only as a result?

Comment: @YasserKhalil `(x.h3.a.text, x.select_one("p.star-rating")['class'][-1], x.select_one("p.price_color").text)`

Answer (score 2):

You could use `page.content.decode('utf-8')` instead of `page.text`. As people in the comments said, it is an encoding issue, and `.content` returns HTML as bytes, then you can convert it into string with right encoding using `.decode('utf-8')`, whereas `.text` returns string with bad encoding (maybe cp1252). The final code may look like this:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as bs4
import requests
import pandas as pd

pages_to_scrape = 1
pages = [] # You forgot this line

for i in range(1,pages_to_scrape+1):
    url = ('http://books.toscrape.com/catalogue/page-{}.html').format(i)
    pages.append(url)
for item in pages:
    page = requests.get(item)
    soup = bs4(page.content.decode('utf-8'), 'html.parser') # Replace .text with .content.decode('utf-8')
    #print(soup.prettify())
for j in soup.findAll('p', class_='price_color'):
    price=j.getText()
    print(price)
```

This should hopefully work

P.S: Sorry for directly writing the answer, I don't have enought reputation to write in comments :D